Encountered an issue adding a row under the for-each-group tag in BI Publisher
While developing the BI Publisher template, I encountered an unexpected issue when attempting to add a row under a left grouping inside the for-each-group tag. This problem is affecting the proper grouping and display of the data.

Expected the result only return 2 rows with data and one row is just added under the 2 rows
I uploaded the XML and template for reproduce the case
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/th43TezE#link
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<!--Generated by Oracle Analytics Publisher -Dataengine, datamodel:-->
<DATA_DS><P_LEDGER/><P_BU/><P_RCV_FM/><P_RCV_TO/><P_PO_DATE_FM/><P_PO_DATE_TO/><P_PO_NUM/><P_SUPPLIER/><P_PROJECT/>
<G_1>
<A>123</A><B>123</B><C></C><D></D><E></E><F></F><G></G><H></H><I></I><J></J><K></K><L>100003</L><M></M><O></O><P>0</P><Q>673.96</Q><R>1</R><S>673.96</S><T>0</T><U>0</U><V>0</V><W>0</W><X>0</X>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<A>456</A><B>456</B><C></C><D></D><E></E><F></F><G></G><H></H><I></I><J></J><K></K><L>100003</L><M></M><O></O><P>0</P><Q>599.07</Q><R>1</R><S>599.07</S><T>0</T><U>0</U><V>0</V><W>0</W><X>0</X>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>

